Is it possible to run 2 Python unitttests that have different patches in a single file?
Let's say you want to test a function that requires input and another that prints output.  This requires two different patches.  I created two distinct classes, but only 1 of them runs.  The sample code shown is stored in a single file, as shown below. Only the first test runs.  I tried running both functions in the same class and got an error.
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

# Test IO functions
from Present import IO

class TestInputEmployeeData(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['Alice', 'Baker'])
    def test_get_user_details(self,mock_input):
        expected_output = {'firstName': 'Alice', 'lastName': 'Baker'}
        result = IO.input_employee_data()
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_output)

class TestOutputErrorMessage(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.print')
    def test_output_error_message(self,mock_print):

        IO.output_error_messages('Invalid input.')
        mock_print.assert_called_once_with('Invalid input.')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()




Can't reproduce, and what you are asking for does work. Attempt to reproduce by replacing/removing your IO calls, both tests from both classes ran. What is the nature of the error you are looking at, please edit your question to include everything that is required to reproduce the error message you are looking at by providing a MVCE.

The answer to your question is: Yes it is possible to have different patches in the same file. Below you can find the details.
I have created the following filesystem structure on my system:
test
  |-Present
  |    |- IO.py
  |-test_builtins.py

I'm using Python 3.6, but there are not many differences regarding this topic in the different versions of the language.
File IO.py
def input_employee_data():
    firstname = input("Enter firstname:")
    lastname = input("Enter lastname:")
    return {'firstName': firstname, 'lastName': lastname}

def output_error_messages(msg):
    print(msg)

File test_builtins.py

The following is exactly your test code

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

# Test IO functions
from Present import IO

class TestInputEmployeeData(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['Alice', 'Baker'])
    def test_get_user_details(self, mock_input):
        expected_output = {'firstName': 'Alice', 'lastName': 'Baker'}
        result = IO.input_employee_data()
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_output)

class TestOutputErrorMessage(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.print')
    def test_output_error_message(self, mock_print):
        IO.output_error_messages('Invalid input.')
        mock_print.assert_called_once_with('Invalid input.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Execution output
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK

So there aren't errors on my system.
NOTE
If I include the tests in only one class it is possible to execute them without problem.

Thanks for answering.  I'm using 3.12 and couldn't run the code as you set it up, but this could be due to a difference in versions.  I made a small change and was able to get it running.  I'm sharing the code that is now working.

This is working for me now in python 3.12
test
  |-Present.py
  |-test_builtins.py

Present.py
class IO:
    pass

    @staticmethod
    def input_employee_data():
        firstname = input("Enter firstname:")
        lastname = input("Enter lastname:")
        return {'firstName': firstname, 'lastName': lastname}

    @staticmethod
    def output_error_messages(msg):
        print(msg)

test_builtins.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

# Test IO functions
from Present import IO

class TestInputEmployeeData(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['Alice', 'Baker'])
    def test_get_user_details(self, mock_input):
        expected_output = {'firstName': 'Alice', 'lastName': 'Baker'}
        result = IO.input_employee_data()
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_output)

class TestOutputErrorMessage(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.print')
    def test_output_error_message(self, mock_print):
        IO.output_error_messages('Invalid input.')
        mock_print.assert_called_once_with('Invalid input.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


I think that the import instruction in test_builtins.py would be from Presentation import IO and not from Present import IO.

Good catch!  I was calling the file Present.py in this example, so I updated the info above.  Thank you.
